# MobileMe SDK/API Documentation

Tags: iphone, macos, mobileme

While searching the web, I've found many references to a "MobileMe API" (or .Mac API) for syncing data with MobileMe, but I can't find any authoritative documentation, even on Apple's site.

Anybody know where it is or how to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a MobileMe API or SDK available right now. 
It was a rumor on WWDC ‘08. Maybe see the light this year.

Comment: So how does the Panic Software's Transmit sync bookmarks over Mobile.Me?

Comment: I think it uses Apple's Sync API

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an api for mobileme, however everything has been developed using standards.

For example, you can access calendar an tasks using CalDAV or you can access iDisk using WebDav.

I hope this helps, because I have been looking for this several months.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Mobile Me SDK.

There is (was) a .Mac SDK but 1) it won't run on the iPhone and 2) hasn't been updated in almost 3 years.

As always, you should [file a request with Apple](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

On a related note, I really don't think Apple does quite a good enough job with developer documentation and community involvement.  They could certainly take a page out of Microsoft's book on that front.